# How to install and config seeder into mikroORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, mikro-orm

Hi I try to run seeders in mikroORM and I found problem. I did everything as is descrbed here: https://mikro-orm.io/docs/next/seeding.

1. Create seeders directory in mikro-orm route folder (next to mikro-orm.config.ts)
2. Updated mikro-orm.ts with this linse:

```
  seeder: {
    path: './seeders', // path to the folder with seeders
    pathTs: './seeders', // path to the folder with TS seeders (if used, we should put path to compiled files in `path`)
    defaultSeeder: 'DatabaseSeeder', // default seeder class name
    glob: '!(*.d).{js,ts}', // how to match seeder files (all .js and .ts files, but not .d.ts)
    emit: 'ts', // seeder generation mode
    fileName: (className: string) => className, // seeder file naming convention
  },
```

and then I try run this command

```
npx mikro-orm seeder:create DatabaseSeeder
```

and get error: Unknown arguments: seeder:create, DatabaseSeeder

There is also no seed command in my mikro-orm commands list so I try install IT:

```
npm i @mikro-orm/seeder
```

and I stuck on this error

```
λ npm i @mikro-orm/seeder
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: anthony-web-app-api@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @mikro-orm/core@4.5.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@mikro-orm/core
npm ERR!   @mikro-orm/core@"^4.5.9" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @mikro-orm/core@"^4.0.0" from @mikro-orm/entity-generator@4.5.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mikro-orm/entity-generator
npm ERR!     peerOptional @mikro-orm/entity-generator@"^4.0.0" from @mikro-orm/core@4.5.10
npm ERR!   6 more (@mikro-orm/mariadb, @mikro-orm/migrations, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @mikro-orm/core@"^5.0.0" from @mikro-orm/seeder@5.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@mikro-orm/seeder
npm ERR!   @mikro-orm/seeder@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\adria\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\adria\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-11T11_29_10_541Z-debug.log
```

I will be very appreciate for any advise how to solve this. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Is your project up to date with the latest version of MikroORM? Could you run `npx mikro-orm debug`?

Seeing this message:

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @mikro-orm/core@"^5.0.0" from @mikro-orm/seeder@5.2.0
```

and this message

```
npm ERR! Found: @mikro-orm/core@4.5.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@mikro-orm/core
npm ERR!   @mikro-orm/core@"^4.5.9" from the root project
```

My best guess is that you are running MikroORM version 4.5. In v5 of MikroORM the seeder was introduced. So you'd need to update to that version before you can use it.

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/upgrading-v4-to-v5